# loading images into an array python

Tags: ipython

i am trying to read my own images which are 28 x 28 dimension: the images are stored in a folder called, my_own_images. and the image name is 2828_my_own_3.png, 2828_my_own_7.png etc...

i am using the imagio.imread(image_file_name, as_gray = True). However i get an error for the as_gray. I am trying to convert them into grey scale

****THE CODE IS BELOW****

*import imageio

import glob

import numpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

my_dataset = []

for image_file_name in glob.glob('my_own_images/2828_my_own_?.png'):

```
print ("loading ... ", image_file_name)
# use the filename to set the correct label
label = int(image_file_name[-5:-4])
# load image data from png files into an array
img_array = imageio.imread(image_file_name)
print(img_array.shape)
# reshape from 28x28 to list of 784 values, invert values
img_data  = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)
# then scale data to range from 0.01 to 1.0
img_data = (img_data / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
print(numpy.min(img_data))
print(numpy.max(img_data))
# append label and image data  to test data set
record = numpy.append(label,img_data)
print(record)
my_dataset.append(record)
pass*
```

**The ERROR im getting:**
open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_gray'

Answer (score 0):

It seems we are reading the same book ([Make Your Own Neural Network](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EER4Z4G)), I have encountered the same error with anaconda (I have imageio 2.2.0 Install), so I updated the imageio to 2.3.0, re-launch jupyter Notebook, re-run the code again it work for me. (hope it help you)